# Get table into a variable from ADO Recorset

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, ado, recordset

I need some help here, I have been trying for days but nothing.

In the following code, I cannot get a variable with the table from the ADO Recordset. I want the data from rs.open in a variable so I can use it in the type of table I want to show. You can see the result in the attached screenshot.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"> 
<script>

var pad = "C:\\Users\\alarcone\\Desktop\\TNParameters.accdb";

var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;

var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

cn.Open(strConn);

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

var SQL = "SELECT ed, df, er FROM Table1";   

rs.Open(SQL, cn);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: rs,
        columns: [
            { title: "ed" },
            { title: "df" },
            { title: "er" }
        ]
    } );
} );

rs.Close();
cn.Close();

</script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad, I apologise, I will remove the downvote.

Comment: No problem peter, thanks.

Comment: The function defined inside document.ready executes well after rs.Close/cn.Close have executed.  I would say try removing or commenting out the two close calls and see if it works.